# shortest code for printing backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm trying to create as short as possible code for printing an input backwards, and I want to go below 60B. My code takes 79B, and have no idea if it is actually possible to shorten it even more.

```
tab=[i for i in map(int,input().split())]
print(" ".join(map(str, tab[::-1])))
```

So when I input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I get in output:

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

Anybody got idea if it can be even shorter?

Comment: Go to code golf for this https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code golf (puzzles where the solution is the shortest code possible) has a dedicated site: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow's scope is explicitly limited to **practical** questions -- and in the real, practical world, terseness is less important than readability (and may also be less important than efficiency, depending on the use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(*input().split()[::-1])
```

Splits the list by spaces, then reverses and sends to print as a bunch of arguments.

`print` supplies the separating space automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One liner *41 Bytes*

```
>>> print(''.join(i for i in input()[::-1]))
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

Altough, you could just reverse the `input()` output w/ subscripting, and print that.

```
>>> print(input()[::-1])
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: OP asked for a program that prints to STDOUT, not REPL

Comment: Updated w/ print @Uriel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you're asking, but if it's just to reverse the string as such, then `print(input()[::-1])` clocks in at 21B.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer -- one should answer *well-asked* questions. Part of being well-asked is being on-topic; and code-golf challenges have a completely separate site.